# Internal Server Error when making multiple API calls within for-loop (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, fetch-api

I'm relatively new when it comes to Typescript/Javascript, but I'm trying to set all indices of `this.articles[i].result` within `setBias()` equal to `setBiasedRating(this.articles[i].url);`, the function containing the API call. So far I have this:

```
async getBiasedRating(url) {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://news-bias-detection-api.herokuapp.com/',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: `{
          "url": "${url}"
        }`,
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

async setBias() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.articles.length; ++i) {
      try {
        this.articles[i].result = await this.getBiasedRating(
          this.articles[i].url
        );
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("Error fetching bias news data");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, when I loop through all the indices in the `this.articles` array and set the `i'th` index equal to the response I get from `getBiasedRating(this.articles[i].url)`, I see many repeating `POST 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`'s.

I have no idea why this is, since if I have the same functionality, just with the first index instead of looping through everything:

```
 async setBias() {
    this.articles[0].result = await this.getBiasedRating(this.articles[0].url)
  }
```

This works just fine, and the data for `this.articles[0]` gets stored correctly. If anyone could explain why the for loop doesn't work here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess, I think the cloud provider is considering these calls as a *`Ddos attack`*, and stop processing them, when you do 50+ calls at a single moment.

Answer (score -1):

HTTP ERROR 500 isn't problem in your code, it's a server problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).